# How to only import JPG on iPad when shooting in RAW+JPEG

Tags: ipad, photos

I shoot in RAW+JPEG mode. When I import photo to the iPad using the camera connection kit, it imports both versions of each file. Is there a way to only import the JPG version?

Comment: Have you found a solution to this at all yet? I would be interested to know myself.

Comment: No solution yet. I'll post an update if I find one.

Comment: It's 2018 now and we still have no solution for this